# Delphi - ODBC driver not supported Message Keeps popping up

Tags: mysql, delphi, odbc

I keep seeing this error message on my pc, but when I transfer the .exe file to another pc and run it works fine and the error message is not popping up. What to do?

Note: I am using Delphi 10.2 and MySQL Workbench with odbc 8.0 Unicode Driver

[ODBC Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diANj.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MQqE.png)

Comment: Do not use screenshots when you want to show text. The error message is clearly another than your question title indicates. Since you show no code this isn't Delphi related either.

Answer (score 1):

Everything works fine now, after backing up the schema and transfer to another PC the stored procedure was not included. So to conclude there is no problem about the odbc version.

Comment: Ok, so please consider deleting your question post.

Comment: This answer is not useful to a future site user, as it is highly unlikely they will make the same mistake and have the same problem.  You should delete both this answer and the original question - the problem was caused by a simple mistake on your part.